How to pass a Map<String, String> with application.yml when keys contain Latin Extended characters
Say, application.yml and a configuration class of the Spring Boot app look like the following
application.yml
conv:
  map:
    ė: e
    ü: u
    somekey: somevalue

###other properties omitted for brevity

Config.java
package foo.bar;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

@Getter
@Setter
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "conv")
public class Config {

    private Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    /*other properties*/
}

At runtime the map property is not populated with all 3 entries. It is the last map entry (somekey: somevalue) that ends up in the map. It is also the same entry whose key doesn't have extended latin characters such as ė and ü.
However, if keys and values for the first two map entries were to be swapped like this
conv:
  map:
    e: ė
    u: ü
    somekey: somevalue

the resulting map would contain exactly three records, which brings up the question - how to deal with extended latin characters if I still want to preserve them as keys in the map?

Create an MCVE that demos your issue.

I am not having any issues with ė as a key in a Map. Is this a character encoding issue when reading the file?

which version of spring boot and java did you use? I have problems with both Spring Boot 2.7.18 (java version 11) and Spring Boot 3.2.5 (java version 17)

I tested with a simple Java app.

Surely you can construct a map with ė as a key. The question was more specific..

When dealing with extended Latin characters in YAML files for Spring Boot applications you need to use proper encoding and decoding to avoid issues with character encoding. You can easily fix it using char codes like \u and not the char litterial.
conv:
  map:
    \u0117: e
    \u00FC: u
    somekey: somevalue

Here:

\u0117 -> ė,
\u00FC -> ü.

This should fix any other problems you have. Here is how to get the Unicode:
System.out.println( "\\u" + Integer.toHexString('÷' | 0x10000).substring(1) ); Link
